# SSRS - Aggregate Function & Counting Frequency of Matching Values

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report with two separate tables referencing two separate datasets.  The first table includes a column which displays some integer value for tagging purposes (ie, 1,2,9,12...etc).  The second table includes many items, each of which displays some value of the aforementioned tag numbers (many to one).  Both dataset contains the same tag# field.

My question is, how can I count the number of matches in the second table that a particular tag number in the first table is attached to?  I know this has to do with an aggregate function, but I think it may also have to do with grouping and I am not sure how to combine the two for the solution I am looking for.

Thanks!

Comment: I *kinda* see what you're getting at, but it would be nice if you could edit your question and add a minimal example for what's in the data sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Tags.TagId, Count(*) AS Matches
FROM Tags 
INNER JOIN TagMatches ON Tags.TagId = TagMatches.TagId
GROUP BY Tags.TagId
```

Comment: I ended up doing a subselect on the entirety of the data...this works as well and is much easier ha.